# Why won't Array.prototype.reduce() take an empty object literal as the initialValue?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working my way through the `functional-javascript-workshop` tutorial recommended by NodeJS (exercise 6).

I've written the following simple code, which is supposed to count the occurrence of every word in an array, and return the results as an object where each key-value pair is `word: # of occurrences`.

```
function countWords (inputWords) {
    return inputWords.reduce(function (obj, current) {
        obj[current] = typeof obj[current] === 'number' ? obj[current] + 1 : 1;
    }, {});
}
```

If I run it with `countWords(['bob'])` I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bob' of undefined`. The carat points to the `typeof obj[current]` expression on the third line.

If I `console.log(obj)` on the first line of the `reduce()` function, it outputs `Object {}`. If I `console.log(typeof obj)` on the first line, it outputs `object`. So why does it think it's undefined? Is this syntax not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of the function will be used as the `obj` argument for the next value in `inputWords`. Since you don't return anything explicitly, JavaScript returns `undefined`. That is why you are getting the error. To fix that, you need to return `obj`.

```
function countWords (inputWords) {
    return inputWords.reduce(function (obj, current) {
        obj[current] = typeof obj[current] === 'number' ? obj.current + 1 : 1;
        return obj;      // Return the accumulated value
    }, {});
}
```

Anyway, your logic can be simplified a bit, by considering the fact that unknown keys will return `undefined` by default, like this

```
function countWords(inputWords) {
    return inputWords.reduce(function (obj, current) {
        obj[current] = (obj[current] || 0) + 1;
        return obj; // Return the accumulated value
    }, {});
}
```